# Find range of the given function : $ f(x) = \frac{e^x}{1+ \lceil x\rceil } $ when $ x \ge 0 $

Tags: functions, exponential-function

> Find the range for $ f(x) = \cfrac{e^x}{1+\lceil x \rceil } $ when $x\ge 0$

My book answers it in a very straight forward manner -

> Here $f(x)$ is defined for all $x \ge 0$ . Also, $f(x)$ is an increasing function in $[0,\infty)$. Thus, range = $[f(0),f(\infty)] = [1, \infty)$

My question is :
How is this function an increasing function in $[0, \infty)$ ?

Comment: Just to be clear, what do you mean by $[x]$? Presumably the greatest integer $\leq x$. Also, why do you think the function is increasing in $[0,\infty)$? The question doesn't ask about montonicity.

Comment: I will edit the question to answer your accordingly. One sec. , Mr. Clayton!

Comment: I've edited the question, @Clayton . Hope it answers your point.

Comment: [It is not increasing, and not continuous (it's easy to prove, but also the plot is quite a good way to see it).](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+e%5Ex%2F%281%2Bfloor%5Bx%5D%29%2C+x%3D1..5) You can show it is increasing (strictly) and continuous on every $[n, n+1)$, though, with $f(n+1)<f(n)$. This will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very good question. For instance, for $x$ just below $1$, we have that
$$ f(0.999) = \frac{e^{0.999}}{1} \approx e,$$
while for $x = 1$ we have
$$ f(1) = \frac{e}{2} < e.$$
So the function is **not** increasing. But it's not so hard to see that it will always be at least $1$, and it becomes unboundedly large. And at integer values, it temporarily decreases, so that every value in $[1, \infty)$ gets hit. I think this is the way to prove the range is $[1, \infty)$.

Comment: You will also need some continuity (piecewise) here in order to argue that the full range is reached (that is, that the function is surjective on $[1,\infty)$).

Comment: @ClementC. Ah, yes. That's very true.

Comment: I see your point there. What if we consider $[1, \infty)$ for checking whether the function is increasing or not? The value of $f(1.2)$ comes out to be 1.6606... 

While that of $f(1.3) = 1.83465...$ and that of $f(2) = 2.46302...$

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali it will always fail at just-before integer values and the integer values themselves. So $1.999$ compared to $2$, for instance.

Comment: Oh yes! I see that now. So, what should be the appropriate way to define the range of the given function for $x \ge 0$ ? Also, @ClementC. raised the point for continuity of this function. If the function is not continuous at certain values for x, then shouldn't it affect the range of the function? While the book suggests it as just $ [ 1 ,\infty) $ ...

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali Read my comment above, after your original question.

Comment: I see that plot. I understood why it is not continuous. Sorry if I'm getting dumb with my doubts but again, how will I define the range of the function then? The function is obviously not surjective on $[1,\infty)$ ...

Comment: I encourage you to revisit your thinking. It is surjective on $[1, \infty)$.

Comment: One sec. :( I'll recheck what I'm saying. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: It is surjective, but not injective.

Comment: The function is not continuous, right? Then how can it be onto or surjective? Am sorry if I'm getting wrong here, but, does continuity has anything to deal with a function being onto or surjective? Or are they both completely disjoint to each other?

Comment: Okay, I see it! Here, for every element in the range, there is a pre-image of it! While for every element in the domain, there is not necessarily a unique image. Right?

Comment: Seems like I got it! :) Thanks a lot everyone for your kind help and patience. @ClementC. and mixedmath !

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali: regarding your comment above: every element $x$ of the domain *has* a unique image $f(x)$ ($f$ couldn't be a function if $x$ were "mapped to more than one $f(x)$"). It is surjective on $[1,\infty)$: every element $y\in[1,\infty)$ has (at least) one preimage $x$ by $f$. It is not injective: some of the elements $y\in[1,\infty)$ have more than one preimage.

Comment: Oopsieeeeeeee! I should get my concepts right next time. Thanks again, Mr. Clement C. ! I really appreciate your contribution for helping me and thousands of other needy ones. God Bless!